# Show array as scentence except first item

Tags: javascript

How can I output an array as a scentence except the (1) item? Let's say the content of the array is: `["!report","Jay","This","is","the","reason"];`
I tried this to output the items after the (1): `(args.slice(1));`however the output now is: "This,is,the,reason", how could I make it output as a normal scentence?

Comment: Please clarify what you want the output to be. Your question title talks about the "first item", but your sample code uses `1`, which with an array is the second item.

Comment: ["!report","Jay","This","is","the","reason"].slice(1);

Comment: @GiacomoPenuti The real point of this question isn't how to not display the first item, it's how to show the results as a readable sentence. Your answer isn't any different than just about everyone else's here.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Of course it shows a readable sentence. But i think using `shift()` to remove first element is more specific in this case (also performance is a bit better).
http://jsben.ch/bcpxi

Comment: @GiacomoPenuti But, that's not what the question is really about. Not to mention that your answer assumes that the first item in the array will no longer be wanted in the array, which was never stated.

Comment: I think we should give best performance answers when both options are avalaible. Right point, removing first element from array was never stated, editing my answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use built in methods, you can append each word
in the array starting at index 1 (second item).

```
// List of words
var words = ["!report","Jay","This","is","the","reason"];

// Empty string
var sentence = "";

// Loop through array starting at index 1 (second item)
for (let i = 1; i < words.length; i++) {

  // Keep appending the words to sentence string
  sentence = sentence + words[i] + " ";
}

// Print the sentence as a whole
console.log(sentence);
```

Or using built in functions:

```
// Array of strings
var array = ["!report","Jay","This","is","the","reason"];

// Cut off the first element, words is still an array though
var words = array.slice(1)

// Join each element into a string with spaces in between
var sentence = words.join(" ")

// Print as full sentence
console.log(sentence)
```

Output:

```
"Jay This is the reason"
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be let i = 1; ?

Answer (score 0):

**[`.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)** returns a new array, so when you access it as a whole, you often see a comma separated list of the array values.

But, `.slice()` along with **[`.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)** does the trick. `.join()` allows you to "join" all the array values as a single string. If you pass an argument to `.join()`, that argument will be used as a separator.

You can then just concatenate a period (`.`) to the end of the string.

```js
console.log(["!report","Jay","This","is","the","reason"].slice(1).join(" ") + ".");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could slice from the second element and join the array.

```js
console.log(["!report","Jay","This","is","the","reason"].slice(2).join(' '));
```

Answer (score 0):

The output you desire is not very clear (do you want to remove only the first item or also the second). However the methods are the same:

you can use [destructuring assignment syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) if you're es6 compliant

```js
const arr = [a,b,...c] = ["!report","Jay","This","is","the","reason"];
let sentence = c.join(" ");
// or
let sentence2 = c.toString().replace(/,/g," ");

console.log (sentence," - ",sentence2);
```

or simply replace with regex and a correct pattern

```js
const arr =  ["!report","Jay","This","is","the","reason"];

let sentence = arr.toString().replace(/^[A-z! ]+?,[A-z ]+?,/,"").replace(/,/g," ");

// or

let sentence2 = arr.toString().replace(/^[A-z! ]+?,/,"").replace(/,/g," ");

console.log (sentence," - ",sentence2);
```

Answer (score -1):

Here it is, check fiddle comments for code explanation.

```js
var a = ["!report","Jay","This","is","the","reason"];

//removes first element from array and implodes array with spaces
var sentence = a.slice(1).join(" ");

console.log(sentence);
```